# multiple screens of the same activity

Tags: android, android-activity

how do i prevent multiple screens of the same activity?

suppose user clicked a couple of things in activity A, went to activity B, returned to activity A, the transition between activity A and activity B went with "`finish();`"

however, when i click the back button in activity A, i still close 3 instances of it, before actually closing the app.
how do i prevent this situation ?

i put this line on the activity

```
 android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

and it doesnt seem to help

Comment: android:noHistory="true" , Add this line to Manifest file for this activity.

Comment: You seem to be calling startActivity too many times. Setting flags like launchMode or noHistory is not a solution. Show the code.

Comment: Agree with @MaciejGórski, activity A should no longer be on the activity stack if you called finish on it.

Comment: the activity has an options menu built in it, and whenever user goes to a different screen, i want the user to come back to the previous screen, the new activity does not start the previous screen, but when i do return to it, i already have 3 instances of it

Answer (score 1):

try by using `finish()` in your `onStop()` of **Activity A**

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: i did try your answer, however this is not what i wanted. I wanted the activity to stay active, so that when i click the back button, i return to that activity, but the result was, if i click back button from within that activity more than once, i seem to be closing several instances of the same activity
however, if i do "finish" on it, there is nothing to "come back " to